# accessing request parameters Parse

Tags: parse-platform, request, undefined, parse-cloud-code

I've got an issue when I try to access the request parameters.

As I've read, we have to use `request.params.someParam` to access the data we're sending via post or get. I'm following these steps, but I obtain an "undefined" response.

The code I use is the following one:

```
app.post('/hello', function(request, response) {

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation); 
query.equalTo('UserName', request.params.userName); //trying to filter by UserName parameter  
response.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

});
```

Does anyone know why do I obtain an undefined response and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a cloud function or background job?

Answer (score 1):

May I ask how do you specify your request params?
Because I found that when I tried to arrange a background job with request.params in Parse WebGUI, it requires to put a double quote (") for each key. Ex. {"userName":"John"}. 
But when the request.params got passed into the background job, the double quote was escaped. Ex. {\"userName\": "John"}. So I can't get the param by request.params.userName
If I send the request via CURL then it all works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665512/entering-in-input-in-background-job-parse
Check this link. I too had the same problem with backgroud job.