# '\' entering in input in background job parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

[image: This]

When I run this background job, this is the log I am getting.

```
I2015-06-05T11:17:37.360Z]v163: Ran job DeleteAccount with:

  Input: "{\"username\":\"9369190589\"}"
```

request.params.username is undefined because  '\' is present. So I am unable to access username. How can I access username from the job

Update: 
Here is the part of code I'm trying

```
Parse.Cloud.job("DeleteAccount", function(request, response){
    var id = request.object.get("username");
    console.log("id = " + id);
});
```

Here is the error:
I2015-06-05T11:06:31.839Z]v163: Ran job DeleteAccount with:

Input: "{\"id\":\"9369190589\"}"

Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

And even request.params.username is also not working

Comment: It's highly unlikely that `\"` is breaking anything. You're _new_ question is also quite different from your _original_ question. You'll need to provide more details about what you're doing (consider writing a new question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment, I will contribute here.

I have the same problem as you. In addition, I noticed that when calling the job with a REST request, the input log is printed as

```
I2015-06-12T16:18:16.285Z]
I2015-06-12T16:18:16.503Z]v44: Ran job XXX with:
    Input: {"api":"2oil4z6k","name_asset":"SX5E"}
    Result: undefined
```

The parameter fo the REST request is declared as
    -d '{"api":"2oil4z6k","name_asset":"SX5E"}'

Whereas when the job is called with the Scheduled Cloud Job the log is printed as

```
I2015-06-12T16:23:27.259Z]
I2015-06-12T16:23:27.432Z]v44: Ran job XXX with:
  Input: "{\"api\":\"2oil4z6k\", \"name\":\"SX5E\"}"
  Failed with: An error has occurred
```

This thime the the parameter is declared in the parameter input as {"api":"2oil4z6k", "name":"SX5E"}

So it seems like the Scheduled Cloud Job is escaping every string in the JSON object.

The solution is to call JSON.parse() on the request.params

```
data = JSON.parse(request.params);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't know about that. I am using REST API to schedule jobs. It is working fine , But I am unable to schedule using Schedule Cloud Job

Comment: After that how to access "name_asset" from 'data' variable

Comment: The same has happend to us, we have manually started a background job with paramenter for months now, and suddenly it stopped working today.

I got it working by using `JSON.parse(request.params)` as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `"` need to be escaped to not close the enclosing `"`.

Compare the syntax highlighting:

```javascript
"a "string""

"a \"string\""
```

The `\` tells you that the following character should not behave in a special way. In this case it means "This is just a quote mark *inside* the string, **don't** close the string!

Answer (score 0):

`\` is used to [escape the literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) which you want to escape. So in your case the first `"` is start of the string and so is the last one. The `"` used in the middle are escaped using the `\`

Comment: But my question is, how to access username from the job.
When I use request.params.username , it is undefined

Comment: @Technoid:- Can you show your code or may be create a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

```
"{\"username\":\"9369190589\"}"
```

The first `"` defines the start of a String. The second, third, forth and fifth are string " (are not parsed) and hence a `\` to indicate nonparsing characters. The last `"` denotes the end of the string

Consider reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 0):

- While you'r inside `"` you dont need to escape `'`(and reverse)
- for print `\` it's usually `\\`
- If you are in `"` and need to print `"` you can use `\"` also if you
  are in `'` and need to print it `\'`

:)